# Imprimir todos lo divisores exactos y la sumatoria de ellos?

Tags: python

Cómo puedo imprimir todos lo divisores exactos de un numero introducido por el usuario al igual que la sumatoria de ellos, usando el operador de modulo `%`?

**Mi código**

```py
num1 = int(input("Introduzca numero: "))
num = 0 
while num >=0: 
    num += 1 
    if (num1 % num == 0): 
        print("Sus divisores son exactos: ", num)
```

Comment: `print(divisores_exactos)` y `print(sumatoria)`, o el nombre que le hayas asignado a tus variables. Por otro lado, te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Para poder ayudarte hace falta más contexto. ¿Cuál es el problema real? ¿Has intentado algo?

Comment: El ejercicio puesto por el maestro dice lo siguiente: "Imprima todos los divisores exactos de un número introducido por el teclado al igual que la sumatoria de ellos."

Comment: Pero no hacemos tareas de escuela. Debes. Mostrar que has intentado algo. De lo contrario tu pregunta terminará cerrada.

Comment: num1 = int(input("Introduzca numero: "))

num = 0
while num >=0:
    num += 1

    if (num1 % num == 0):
        print("Sus divisores son exactos: ", num)

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/467169/edit) tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante 
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta). 
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!

Comment: Aun estás a tiempo de rescatar tu pregunta! c: Edítala y agrega el código que pasaste en los comentarios. Existe la posibilidad de que la comunidad vote para reabrir tu pregunta y por lo tanto puedas recibir respuestas!

Comment: y que es lo que se te dificulta?, cual es tu problema?

Answer (score 1):

Hay algunos errores en tu código que he corregido. El primero es que tenías un bucle infinito, ya que la condicion del while está mal, tal y como tienes el codigo la variable `num` siempre será mayor o igual que cero. Debes recordar que el divisor máximo de un numero entero será él mismo. De esta forma, por ejemplo, el maximo divisor de 10 es, obviamente, 10. Entonces el while quedaría `while num <= num1`.

He creado una lista llamada `divisores_exactos` donde guardaremos cada divisor. De esta forma es muy facil cumplir con los dos requerimentos que deseas: Listar los divisores exactos y la suma de ellos.

```
num1 = int(input("Introduzca numero: "))
num = 0
divisores_exactos = []
while num <= num1: 
    num += 1 
    if (num1 % num == 0): 
        divisores_exactos.append(num)

suma_divisores = sum(divisores_exactos)
print("Sus divisores exactos son:", divisores_exactos)
print("La suma de los divisores es:", suma_divisores)
```

Salida:

```
Introduzca numero: 10
Sus divisores exactos son: [1, 2, 5, 10]
La suma de los divisores es: 18
```

Answer (score 0):

Pues, dentro del `if (num1 % num == 0):` puedes sumarle `num` a algún acumulador, `suma` o como lo quieras llamar, que también puedes inicializar en cero.
Ya por fuera del while puedes hacer `print` del contenido de `suma` y ya está, no?